# Program Input only recognizing words not lines

Tags: c++

I wrote this program for a school project where the user inputs up to 4 lines of text then types "end" and it repeats it to them in reverse order. It works fine, except it is recognizing a "line" to be only 1 word so if I try and type a line (Ex. the quick brown fox jumps over the log) it doesn't use that as a line but each word as a line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main()
{
        string l1;
        string l2;
        string l3;
        string l4;
        string l5;
        bool end (false);
        while (end == false)
{
        cout<<"Welcome! Type one sentence then press enter, up to 4 sentences. When finished$
        cin >> l1;
        if (l1 == "end")
        {
        cout << "Error! Must enter at least 1 line of text!" << endl;
        break;
        }
        cin >> l2;
        if (l2 == "end")
        {
        cout<<l1<<endl;
        end = true;
        break;
        }
        cin >> l3;
        if (l3 == "end")
        {
        cout<<l2<<endl;
        cout<<l1<<endl;
        end = true;
        break;
        }
        cin >> l4;
        if (l4 == "end")
        {
        cout<<l3<<endl;
        cout<<l2<<endl;
        cout<<l1<<endl;
        end = true;
        break;
        }
        cin >> l5;
        if (l5 == "end")
        {
        cout<<l4<<endl;
        cout<<l3<<endl;
        cout<<l2<<endl;
        cout<<l1<<endl;
        end = true;
        break;
        }
        else
        {
        cout<<"Error! Please enter 4 or less lines"<<endl;
        break;
        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::getline` instead of `operator>>`.  The `operator>>` reads words, not text lines.